# Question on homotopy of maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am stuck on the following qualifying Exam question.  I would appreciate any help.

Let $RP^2$ and $T$ denote the eal projective plane and the torus.  Prove that any map $f: RP^2 \rightarrow T$ is homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: (Did you mean $\mathbb{R}P^2$?)  What do you know about lifting maps?

Answer (score 2):

Any map $f:RP^2 \longrightarrow T$ induces a map on the fundamental groups, and hence we get a map $f_*:\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.  Any such map is trivial.

Now consider the universal cover of the torus, $p:\mathbb{R^2} \longrightarrow T$.  Since the image of our map is trivial, it certainly lies inside $p_*(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)) = \{{1}\}$.  So by the lifting criterion, there exists a lift $\tilde f:RP^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f = p \circ \tilde f$.  Noting that $\mathbb{R^2}$ is contractible, this might help you find your nullhomotopy.